# How to update component data after calling mounted function?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to update my component's data after calling an API (calling method from mounted function)

```
axios.get("getInfo")
    .then(function(res){
        this.result = res.data.result
        }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
})
```

however the "this.result = res.data.result" doesn't get executed but when i paste the same line before the call, I get result updated (like this.data.result = 20). Also when I try the console.log(res.data) I get no response

I also get the message on the console that the request was completed

> XHR finished loading: GET "http://app/getInfo".

My mounted function is like this

```
mounted:function(){
   this.setData()
}, 
methods:{
   setData:function(){
      console.log(this.pullData())
   },
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: is 'this.result' supposed to be pointing to your component data object?

Comment: yes, I have 
    `data: function(){
        return {
            result:{year:''}
        }
    }`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to store the reference to the component in a variable firstly, then refer to it in the function with the variable instead of *this* keyword; The reason is that you created a new function in `then`, `this` thus refers to the function instead of the Vue component:

```js
var ref = this;

axios.get("getInfo")
    .then(function(res){
        ref.result = res.data.result
//      ^^^ ref instead of this         
        }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
})
```

And another more straight forward way to do this is to use arrow function which doesn't have a `this` context:

```js
axios.get("getInfo").then(res => {     // arrow function instead of anonymous function
  this.result = res.data.result
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Holy, thanks!!! This worked lke a charm, and it was that easy... can't belive it. Thanks <3

Comment: Worked for me too, thank you for this answer.